# Emulator in Eclipse on Mac OS X

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

This is my first time running Eclipse on a mac. For some reason, when I launch an app in the emulator, while the console tells me that it successfully started the app, I can't see an emulator window anywhere. I know its running bc when I tried again, console told me "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front."

How do I find the emulator?!

Comment: s/b there, the mac isn't so different from anything else.  try alt-tab?

Comment: Maybe try to restart Eclipse? Also, try to manually start the emulator from Eclipse-Window-Android SDK and AVD Manager, and only then launch the activity. (I use Eclipse on Mac OS, and it works fine)

Comment: Click the simulator icon in the dock. Also, there's always Exposé (F9).

Comment: Tje 'not started' message means that your apk was not changed (you clicked the launch again, so this is expected). The app did  not have to be reinstalled to the emulator, so you get the message that it did not start a new activity, just 'woke' the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm using MotoDev Studio. Apparently I had to click the little cell phone icon in the bottom right to bring up the emulator.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cycling through open applications with command-tab or clicking on the application icon in the dock?  Running applications will have a bright dot under them.

Comment: Tried that and other suggestions...still nothin'. I must be missing something basic here :-/

Comment: Have you tried using the AVD Manager to launch the emulator?  Do you see any sort of window pop up?